# Проблема с буферизированными потоками в Java

Tags: потоки-данных, java

Здравствуйте =)
Прошу Вас, чтобы Вы мне объяснили причину возникновения такой вот проблемы. Вот маленький код клиент-серверного приложения.

Клиент:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 2001);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
        System.out.println("step1");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("step2");
        in.close();
        out.close();
```

Сервер:

```
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2001);
    Socket socket = ss.accept();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
    System.out.println("step1");
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("step2");
    in.close();
    out.close();
```

При запуске обе консольки выводят только step1 и "виснут".

Если не использовать буфер, т.е. не "заворачивать" получаемые потоки от сокета в Buffered..Stream, то все работает ожидаемо.

В чем проблема моя? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ObjectOutputStream при создании прописывает заголовок, а ObjectInputStream при создании соответственно, его читает. При использовании буферизации эти заголовки застревают в буферах. Чтобы их протолкнуть, надо после out=new ObjectOutputStream() поставить out.flush().

Comment: Интересно, хотя не совсем понял. Но решение есть. Спасибо!